# create Fast Report using FDMemtable

Tags: delphi, fastreport

we want to use fast reports with a Fire Dac memory table component.
I can populate the memory table at the run time  of my  program, but I fail to
design a report (frxReport)  as there are no data in the dataset at design time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all - you don't need data to design reports. Yeah it's not so easy as with data, but not necessary.

Second - you can add some test data in design time manually or (if you need complex or lot of data) you can export it in a file at runtime `FDMemTable1.SaveToFile('C:\temp\data.xml', sfXML)` and import it for testing at desingtime (popup menu of FDMemTable->Load from file...).

P.S. Don't forget to add component TFDStanStorageXMLLink to export data successful at runtime.

Comment: in my table is the path stored to an image ,  i must plot  the image in my report

Comment: You can do it same as an runtime by FastScript in report at DesignTime.